# Entity Framework 7 relationship issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

In EF 7 (beta 6) i'm using code-first and i made this code:

```
public class User {
    // Primary key
    public int Id {get;set;}
    // Some attributes
    public string FirstName {get; set;} 
    public string LastName {get; set;}
    // Foreign keys
    public int CityOfBirthId {get;set;}
    public int CityHomeId {get;set;}
    // Navigation methods
    [ForeignKey("CityOfBirthId")]
    public virtual City CityOfBirth {get;set;}
    [ForeignKey("CityHomeId")]
    public virtual City CityHome {get;set;}
}

public class City {
    // Primary key
    public int Id {get;set;}
    // Attributes
    public string Name {get;set;}
    // Navigation methods
    [InverseProperty("CityOfBirth")]
    public virtual ICollection<User> UsersBorn {get;set;}
    [InverseProperty("CityHome")]
    public virtual ICollection<User> UsersHome {get;set;}
}
```

I also added this code in my ApplicationDBContext

```
public DbSet<User> Users {get;set;}
public DbSet<City> Cities {get;set;}
```

I've some problems with migration tool. With just on relation per entity (for example i just write CityHome relation) it works, but with two relations (like the code above) the migration tool doesn't create relations. In the tables i get only attributes and CityOfBirthId and CityHomeId are just int attributes istead of foreign keys.

Comment: With just one it work, but when you try both, both dosen't work ? Maybe a strange behavier of Entity, not wanting tow foreign key to relate the same table...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to beta7.  Data attributes are not recognized in beta 6.

Ref https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/pull/2756